# Cypress - find table row based on unique combination of elements

Tags: cypress

I have a table where I can add records (rows).

I would like to find a record(row) which has unique combination of items. This record(row) is somewhere among randomly ordered other records. Then I would like to work with that one only row.

Example: I would like to identify a row, which has validfrom:2021-07-24 00:00 , validto:2021-07-28 23:59 and region:CZ. After identifying this row I would like to verify that all it's items are as they should be.

I tried this, but it always verify items from another records:

```
 cy.contains(platform).parent('td').parent('tr').within(() => {
            cy.get('td').eq(3).should('contain', platform)
            cy.get('td').eq(4).should('contain', saleType)
            cy.get('td').eq(9).should('contain', region)
            cy.get('@validFromInsertedAlias').then(validFromInsertedAlias => {
                cy.get('td').eq(6).invoke('text').then(validFromSaved => {
                    cy.log('overeni valid from')
                    expect(validFromInsertedAlias).to.include(validFromSaved)
                })
            })
            cy.get('@validToInsertedAlias').then(validToInsertedAlias => {
                cy.get('td').eq(7).invoke('text').then(validToSaved => {
                    cy.log('overeni valid to')
                    expect(validToInsertedAlias).to.include(validToSaved)
                })
            })
        })
```

platform, saleType and region are variables received from another method.

Comment: Are those things you want to identify the row properties or elements?

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to get an element by containing a nonUnique value, that is present somewhere else in the dom. Here is how I would approach it:

```
cy.contains('tableUniqueSelector td', platform) //The unique selector is important, because the value is probably represented on other tables in the dome
    .parents('tr')
    .within(rowElement => {
        const rowElementHtmlToString = JSON.stringify(rowElement.html())
        cy.get('@validFromInsertedAlias')
            .then(validFromInsertedAlias => {
                if (rowElementHtmlToString.includes(validFromInsertedAlias)) {
                    throw new Error('Row is missing ValidFrom value') //Those will ensure the row is correct
                }
                cy.get('td').eq(6).invoke('text').then(validFromSaved => {
                    cy.log('overeni valid from')
                    expect(validFromInsertedAlias).to.include(validFromSaved)
                })
            })
        cy.get('@validToInsertedAlias')
            .then(validToInsertedAlias => {
                if (rowElementHtmlToString.includes(validToInsertedAlias)) {
                    throw new Error('Row is missing ValidTo value') //Those will ensure the row is correct
                }
                cy.get('td').eq(7).invoke('text').then(validToSaved => {
                    cy.log('overeni valid to')
                    expect(validToInsertedAlias).to.include(validToSaved)
                })
            })
        cy.get('td').eq(3).should('contain', platform)
        cy.get('td').eq(4).should('contain', saleType)
        cy.get('td').eq(9).should('contain', region)
    })
```